# how to send an image in the body of the mail using any of the mail utilities in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, html, jpeg, mailx

How can we send an image in the body of a mail with rich text / HTML.

I tried to get from few of the links , but i am not able to get complete solution. I tried below code but no luck

```
mpack -s "TEST mail" -c image/jpeg Abc158.jpg abc@gmail.com
```

I have tried using "mailx" but i am unable to send image in body of the mail

```
mailx -s "TEST mail" ABC@gmail.com < file1.jpg
```

Please help me with any suggestion

Comment: Do you need to use an external SMTP server, or just locally installed MTA?

Comment: @grawity. Thanks a lot for the reply. I have linux server installed ,